# Android Youtube Download mp3

Tags: android, stream, download, youtube, mp3

Assume I have the id (The numbers and signs in the video's hyperlink after "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=") of a Youtube video. How can  I download the audio stream of the file to an sd-card as an mp3 with android code? (I wrote an application for 2.x but this part is missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how some other YouTube scrapers do it, e.g. [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/). Then recreate their algorithm in Java for Android. Then keep spending time trying to stay up-to-date with the capricious changes YouTube will make to their site every now and then.